# Как задать голос хозяина

Tags: python, windows, распознавание-речи

Как привязать VOSK к голосу только 1 человека? Ну или не обязательно что бы это был воск можно и что либо другое главное что-б работало только с 1 голоса и только на 1 слово (дальше уже адаптирую). Сири, гугл, биксби, алиса это умеют, а у меня распознаёт всё что не приколочено, а из за мощей микрофонов так ещё и соседские голоса...